# What is the wrong in the following MySql query?

Tags: mysql

```
create table rolemaster(roleno int(2) not null,
                        primary key(roleno),
                        rolename varchar(20));

create table roombed(roomnumber varchar(10),
                     bednumber varchar(10) not null primary key,
                     username varchar,
                     foreign key(username) references roleusers(username));
```

It is showing

> ErrorNr: 1064.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: crazy concept; you can not reference a column that does not exist as the target of a foreign key.

Comment: references roleusers(username) there is no username in roleusers

Comment: @P.Salmon there is no `roleusers` at all in the question.

Comment: table `roleusers` maybe already exists.

Comment: references can refer to other existing table

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca why should that be wrong or relevant for the error? It is `primary key(roleno)` so it is a valid create definition, and as it is after the `roleno` it is valid.

Comment: @t.niese never seen it done like that. Today I learned something, thank you

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca this can be used to define composite primary keys, in example : `PRIMARY KEY (foreign_key1, foreign_key2)`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
create table roleusers(username varchar(10) not null primary key );

create table rolemaster(roleno int(2) not null primary key ,
                        rolename varchar(20));

 create table roombed(roomnumber varchar(10),
                     bednumber varchar(10) not null primary key,
                     username varchar(10),
                     foreign key (username) references roleusers (username));
```

Ive added a roleusers table so I can give you a working script.

EDIT : What you were doing wrong for starters was the comma before the primary key. 
The foreign key you added to a table we dont know about have to reference a key on the other table so in the example posted Ive added a roleusers table setting `username` as a primary key so it could be referenced later as a foreign key.
You had also forgotten to correctly define the varchar on username. as mentioned by another answer.

Hope this explanation helps

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca you are right. Added a brief explanation

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to define a size for `username varchar`.

```
CREATE TABLE roombed
(
    roomnumber VARCHAR(10),
    bednumber VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(10),
    --              ^--^----------- This
    FOREIGN KEY(username) REFERENCES roleusers(username)
);
```